# oddsratio expecting 2 x 2 in R

Tags: r, contingency

odds ratio expecting 2 x 2 in R. It appears that I have created a 2 x 2 table...hmm, even prop.table() display data as 2 x 2 table, so what odds ratio function will work with my table?

Data:

```
nausea_yes <- c(98, 161, (98-161))
nausea_no <- c(264, 280, (264-280))
```

Table formed OK:

```
tbl <- table(nausea_yes, nausea_no)
tbl.prop <- prop.table(tbl, margin=1)
```

```
          nausea_no
nausea_yes -16 264 280
       -63   1   0   0
       98    0   1   0
       161   0   0   1
```

Problem Code:

```
library(mosaicCore)
nausea_yes <- c(98, 161, (98-161))
nausea_no <- c(264, 280, (264-280))
tbl <- table(nausea_yes, nausea_no)
tbl.prop <- prop.table(tbl, margin=1)
odds_ratio <- mosaic::oddsRatio(tbl.prop, verbose = TRUE)
```

Error:

```
Error in orrr(x, conf.level = conf.level, verbose = verbose, digits = digits, : expecting something 2 x 2
```

Comment: As per the error, it is expecting 2 x 2 matrix and not 3 x 3 (3 columns, 3 rows)

Comment: You're doing it all wrong. Try using `cbind` without the marginal totals, and then maybe `fisher.test`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `cbind` to create the 2x2 table, not `table`. Then you can use `fisher.test` to get the odds ratio, with the null that it is equal to 1 (no difference).

```
nausea_yes <- c(98, 161)
nausea_no <- c(264, 280)
tbl <- cbind(nausea_yes, nausea_no); tbl
#     nausea_yes nausea_no
#[1,]         98       264
#[2,]        161       280

fisher.test(tbl)
#Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

#data:  tbl
#p-value = 0.004974
#alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
#95 percent confidence interval:
# 0.4712971 0.8827141
#sample estimates:
#odds ratio 
#  0.645947
```

---

Interpretation is complicated since we don't know the row names, although I'm sure you know. All we can say is that the first row has a lower odds of "nausea_yes" than the second row. If the first row represented a treatment group, then we could say that there was a significantly lower odds of nausea among the treatment group.

Note that the `table` function is used to tabulate raw data in order to obtain frequency counts. But since you've already got the frequency counts, there's no need to use `table` here. Just combine the counts with `cbind` (or `rbind`).

Answer (score 1):

According to `?oddsRatio`

> This function calculates the odds ratio and relative risk for a 2 x 2 contingency table and a confidence interval (default conf.level is 95 percent) for the each estimate. x should be a matrix, data frame or table.
>
> The odds ratio is calculated as (Odds row 2) / (Odds row 1)

---

In the OP's example, it is a 3 x 3 table/matrix and not 2 x 2

If it is a 2 x 2 matrix, it should work

```
nausea_yes <- c(98, 161)
nausea_no <- c(264, 280)
mosaic::oddsRatio(cbind(nausea_yes, nausea_no))
#[1] 1.54898
```